# Jenkins dashboard not showing job status

Tags: jenkins

I am having intermittent issues with Jenkins where the dashboard will indicate
that a job has never been run even though it has.

The files and folders from the previous build(s) are all in place and, if I run
the build again, it usually updates the status correctly after the build
completes. However, that status may go back to indicating that the job has
never been built at a later time.

Most of the time it is not the latest job/build which loses its status.  The
status may switch to the correct data after a different job is built, but not
always.

I have yet to determine any kind of pattern as to which builds are being
ignored, much less why.

Has anyone else seen this behavior?

Update: I am running Jenkins 1.497 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I am also facing a similar one after I upgraded to 1.490 and a few plugins including the configuration slicing plugin. So it has to be one of them. What all plugins do you have ?

Comment: Plugins installed are Jenkins Mailer 1.4, External Monitor Job Type 1.1, LDAP 1.2, pam-auth 1.0, ant 1.1, javadoc 1.0, Jenkins Active Directory 1.30, Jenkins CSV 2.7, Maven Integration 1.494, Email-ext 2.24.1, Green Balls 1.12, Jenkins SSH Slaves 0.22, Subversion 1.43, and Jenkins Translation Assistance 1.10.

Comment: only 1 match from my set. I got Jenkins 1.491 and email-ext plugin. So.. looks like it has to be the Jenkins upgrade. Have you checked the `Discard Old Builds` section in the job config? Is it deleting your old jobs. In that case it shows N/A. Is that what your are able to see ?

Comment: The old jobs were not being deleted, they just were not showing up on the dashboard. All of the files seemed to be intact in the appropriate folders. The problem has not recurred since I upgraded to version 1.494.

Comment: ok.. should we either get this question closed or put "downgrade Jenkins" as the answer ?

Comment: Either downgrade or upgrade. However, when I upgraded to 1.494, I lost the ability to send email notifications via my corporate smtp host.

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon, as the same problem is now happening with version 1.497. I reported it as an issue at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16175 but it has yet to be assigned or drawn any responses there.

Comment: I am thinking will it worthwhile to disable all but core plugins, and install one by one.

Comment: I just did a fresh install of Jenkins 1.498 on a different server and this problem is happening again. Still no response from the Jenkins JIRA people on the issue I submitted last month.

Comment: From what I've seen on https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/ this problem has been occurring since version 1.477 (or earlier) back in September. The workaround is to "Reload Configuration from Disk" via the manage page. This won't prevent the problem from reoccurring, but will hopefully display all of the builds.

Comment: 1 up .. thanks a lot .. I guess this is what I was looking for .. at least have a workaround till they fix it.

Comment: Here is the main discussion for this issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15156

Comment: The issue has supposedly been fixed with Jenkins version 1.502.

Comment: thanks for being so disciplined with the follow-ups. I might have ignored this till the problem really started bothering me. 1 up :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue has supposedly been fixed with Jenkins version 1.505. (Fix put in for version 1.502 was apparently insufficient)

Comment: The issue has been reopend at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15156
At least one user has noticed the problem still occurring with failed builds disappearing from the history.

Comment: Someone else has now reported the problem still exists for them with version 1.505, so don't assume this is completely fixed.